# Summation, solution verification

Tags: summation, solution-verification

Do we have that:$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i1}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i1}x_{i2}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i2}^2} x_{i2})^2={\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i1}^2-\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i1}x_{i2})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i2}^2}}$?. If we have that how can I show it?

Comment: Can you change the indices inside the sum to $j$?

Answer (score 2):

Via tedious expansion.

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_{i1} - \frac {\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j1}x_{j2}}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j2}^2}x_{i2}\right)^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_{i1}^2 - 2x_{i1}x_{i2}\frac {\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j1}x_{j2}}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j2}^2}+\left(\frac {\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j1}x_{j2}}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j2}^2}\right)^2x_{i2}^2\right)
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_{i1}-2\frac {\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j1}x_{j2}}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j2}^2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i1}x_{i2}+\left(\frac {\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j1}x_{j2}}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j2}^2}\right)^2\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i2}^2
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_{i1}-2\frac {\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j1}x_{j2}\right)^2}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j2}^2}+\frac {\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j1}x_{j2}\right)^2}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j2}^2}
\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_{i1}-\frac {\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j1}x_{j2}\right)^2}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j2}^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense

Comment: @Lifeni Then accept the answer. Thanks.